# Mavericks and App nap

Tags: macos, adobe-flash, app-nap

One thing i've been wondering about is how Mavericks handles flash etc....

In the demo that Craig F did on stage, he hid a browser video (or animation) behind another window and then the activity monitor usage dropped to 0 for that process.

That's all great, but my question is what if you want the animation or video to run, because it's a game you DONT want paused, or a video that you're happy for it to keep running, is it the case that now when you have a hidden window that everything ceases to run in that window?

ie. I'm watching something on youtube, if I spend 5 mins sending a mail, and I go back to youtube the video will be where it was before I started the mail? (for me this is undesirable)

Same with say flash games or animations, I may to load a page, go do something else and go back to the page, now all will pause, how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get somethings wrong about App Nap :

If the app « does something for you » (expression used by [apple](http://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/)), I won't be stopped. So videos on youtube will continue to play while your doing other things.

It's also the same with flash games/animations. If they do something they won't be paused.

Comment: Interesting, then how does this piece of the demo work: at approx 16mins in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyXdH5JjMLI   --- you can see that a video is playing and then stops because the process usage goes to zero, surely this is 'doing something for me' but also it seems paused?

Comment: The example you show is exactly what apple wants : It's a passive animation. It's only doing something when it has focus. There is no music in background that you would need to keep.

Comment: Just for clarity, how is this considered passive and a youtube video is not? what is the differential sound? -- or is it because this is rendered in real time?

Comment: Apple does not indicate how it works, so we can only make suppositions.